# Appcelerator build fails when compiling to iOS

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm getting this error when trying to compile my app to iOS:

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   CompileC build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WatchSessionModule.o Classes/WatchSessionModule.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

- Appcelerator Studio build: 4.5.0.201602170821
- Titanium SDK - 5.1.2.GA
- Xcode - Version 7.2.1
- OS - 10.11.3 iOS - iOS 9.2.1 (iPhone 4S)

Compiling to android works fine.

Comment: Long shot, but try cleaning your project, then rebuild your app.

Comment: Thanks! But already did that. I've also completely removed Xcode, Appcelerator, npm module, and installed all again. But this bug remains...

Comment: Today 5.2.0.GA has been released. If possible, can you upgrade and test. Sometimes, sdk upgrade might fix such issues. Also are you trying to build with has some link with Apple Watch?

Comment: Yes, I've tested the 5.2.0.GA and I still cannot compile to iOS. I've also deleted previous SDK versions. I thought It had something to do with Xcode, because build fails after "Invoking xcodebuild". I reinstalled xcode, but the result is the same. This was the first time I've attempted to build to iOS since upgrading from Titanium to Appcelerator. With titanium iOS and Android worked like a charm. Now with Appcelerator only iOS is failing. I already tried all possible solutions found on the web with problems similar to mine. But none work!

Comment: After you have installed XCode, launch it once first, before you build appcelerator. Sometimes it shows you terms and conditions to agree in xcode, which might interupt the build. I read it somewhere. Can you give this a shot.

Comment: This is a similar to the one you are getting:: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19379. You can try to raise a JIRA if you want.

Comment: @Soumya Yes, I've opened xcode. I've also read that issue in Jira, but theres no solution in it. I'm going to raise a Jira for mine, and send them an email. The weird thing is that I installed all in a colleague's mac (same appcelerator, same xcode, node version...) and in is mac, it is working. The only difference is that he has a macbook from 2013 and mine is from 2012... Thank you for taking the time to try to help me.

Comment: Please do create an Appcelerator JIRA ticket for this as Stack Overflow is not the place for bug reports.

Comment: That's interesting. All current releases (5.1.2.GA and 5.2.0.GA) should work with Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7.x. To troubleshoot the issue properly, please provide a trace log of your build and reference it in a http://jira.appcelerator.org as Fokke mentioned above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the OS version. I encountered the same issue while trying to use `v9.0` (Simulator).
I tried to build a lot of times, but no luck. Then I just changed the version to `v9.1`. And then it works!

Might have something to do with the OS version that Titanium Plugin supported. I don't know, just a guess.